# UISearchBar background fading in and out when segue push animates

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6, uinavigationbar

I created two views that has its transition controlled by a navigation view controller. I have a `UIView` which contain a `UISearchBar`. The `UIView` is then set as the navigation bar's `titleView` in the first view.

Now, the problem is, whenever I go from the first view to the second view, I can see a light background behind the `UISearchBar` fading in and out.

I have did a bit of troubleshooting of my own and found that the background belongs to the `UISearchBar` and not the `UIView` that contains it. I have also tried many codes to make the `UISearchBar` background transparent, but none of the codes actually makes it transparent.

[image]

**Edit:** I did a bit more fiddling and found that the colour fading in and out is the colour from the style/tint of the `UISearchBar`. So if I change the tint to black, it'll darken instead. The only way I see I can fix this is to turn the background of the `UISearchBar`'s alpha to 0, but I can't find any code that can change the alpha of a `UISearchBar` in a `UINavigationBar`.

**Edit:** I really can't find any code to turn the background tint of the `UISearchBar` to be alpha 0. Does anyone have a workaround or an alternative solution to this?

Comment: Anyone? I've been trying to find a solution to this since last night...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that the bar is actually the scope bar's background. I'm not sure why it still showed up even though I disabled it. My solution was to set the background image as a transparent image.

```
[self.searchBar setScopeBarBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transpixel.png"]];
```